# How Do I Install a Webmin Module?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, ftp

I found that my Webmin doesn't come with the vsftpd module to configure vsftpd. I found on their site that that they have a download tarball. I downloaded it, but don't know what the proper steps are to add this tarball into the webmin config.

I'm running Ubuntu Server 9.10 with Webmin 1.510, if that matters.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

logon to webmin then,
Webmin > Webmin configuration > Webmin Modules > (check) Third party module from ... then click buton labeled "..." find VSFTPD module on the list. click the module name. it will give you the module installation link in main window. then install...

but, that module may be is not providing more options for vsftpd. 
i think you will use "edit config file" option most of time.